# Export configuration data from module

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, module, nconf

I want to use the nconf module to retriever configuration data from a file(s) according to a policy and export the properties in the JSON configuration files as a module like so:

```
import * as config from 'ConfigData'

console.log(config.MyProperty)
```

The ConfigData module is just wrapping nconf defining the policy of the naming scheme of the config files and what order to load the files.

```
var myconfig = new nconf.Provider({
  env: true,
  argv: true,
  stores: [
     { type: 'file', file: path.join(__dirname, 'config.json')},
     { type: 'file', file: path.join(__dirname, 'default-config.json')}
  ] 
});
```

How do I export the config properties in the JSON file and how does the client code use it?